# Не сохраняются данные в UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Если переключаюсь между `UserControl`'ами то данные в них не сохраняются *(Стираются - не элементы а данные в виде текста)*

Использую данный код: (Нашёл на соседнем борде )

```
public static void ControlVisible(Panel Panl, UserControl Uc)
{
  var ctrl = Panl.Controls.OfType<UserControl>().FirstOrDefault(predicate: g => g.Name == Uc.Name);
  if (ctrl != null)
  {
     ctrl.BringToFront();
  }
  else
  {
     Panl.Controls.Add(value: Uc);
     Uc.BringToFront();
  }
}
```

Для показа (когда переключаюсь по `UserControl`) использую данный метод:

```
ControlVisible(Panel, new UserControl()); 
// UserControl - имя нужного Usercontrol'a где находятся элементы. 
// Panel - Компонент Panel куда показывается usercontrol
```

Если ввожу какие-нибудь данные в один `Usercontrol` и переключусь на другой `UserControl` то при возврате на предыдущий юзерконтрол  данные стёртые.

Подскажите как это исправить?

P.S: Ну по идем этот способ должен работать корректно, может быть у меня какой-то глюк :(

Comment: Где назначается `Uc.Name`?

Comment: @Igor, У меня без `g => g.Name == Uc.Name` вообще не переключается по `usercontrol`ам. А назначение идёт в строчках после `else`

Comment: Вопрос выше был задан не про сам `UserControl`, а про его имя. Где вы конкретно его задаете? У вас вообще в `if` условие заходит? Предположу, что нет, ибо ваше условие `g.Name == Uc.Name` всегда будет `false` и все потому, что вы пытаетесь взять контрол, имя которого не задано. P.S. Не забывайте указывать метку WinForms/WPF вопросу!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А получается тогда нигде, хмм это странно но без него у меня не отображается ничего. А вот если с ним  то тогда данные не сохраняются.

Comment: @GooliveR Я до сих пор не вижу, где вы задаете **имя** (свойство **Name**) у `UserControl`! Вот тут `new UserControl()` - `UserControl` не имя. Именем будет что то вроде этого: `new UserControl(){Name = "superName"}` или `var ctrl = new UserControl(); ctrl.Name = "superName"`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Ну у меня просто без передачи так и стоит. Но без него ничего не работает :( Для показа я просто использую: `ControlVisible(myPanel, new FrmControl()); ` Если использовать весь тот код который я записал, то там всё переключается, но просто данные не сохраняются, а мне нужно именно с сохранением.

Comment: @GooliveR У Вас и "с ним" ничего не работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, А вот имя какое должно задаваться?  Для какого контрола?

Comment: @GooliveR Имя здесь вообще не при чем. У Вас в стопке контролов - контролы разного типа?

Comment: @Igor, Как понимать разного типа? Все Имена UserControl'ов разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А назначение идёт в строчках после `else`

Вы не видите введенных значений, потому что все время добавляете и показываете новый контрол. Как может что-то найтись по `Name`, если во время поиска у `Uc` еще нет никакого `Name`?

```
var ctrl = Panl.Controls.FirstOrDefault(predicate: g => g.GetType() == Uc.GetType());
```

Comment: У меня тогда возникает такая проблема: Если я убираю всё в `if` и `linq` и оставляю `Panl.Controls.Add(value: Uc);` и`Uc.BringToFront();` - то у меня данные не сохраняются, Если же убираю наоборот то у меня не переключается по контролам.

Comment: @GooliveR Перечитайте мой ответ. Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Comment: А в чём отличие GetType() от Name ?  А да и там требуется такая запись: `var ctrl = Panl.Controls.OfType<UserControl>().FirstOrDefault(g => g.GetType() == Uc.GetType());`

Comment: @GooliveR Отличие в том, что тип у контрола есть, а имени - нет. Такая запись там не требуется.

Comment: Подскажите а как ещё можно сделать проверку с этим: `Panl.Controls.Add(value: Uc);`  и `Uc.BringToFront();` Без использования `var ctrl` ?!

Comment: Или к примеру как сделать проверку что   `Panl.Controls.Add(Uc);` уже добавлен без linq

Comment: @GooliveR Хм, я уже показал. Посмотрите последнюю строчку ответа.